# styling text in a pdf using itextsharp in asp.net windows form?

Tags: itext

I have created a PDFs file using itextsharp. Now I want to change the text format like bold, italics or times new roman & etc, and I want to change the size of the text. I don't know how to do that. So I need help, you can suggest me any video tutorials also.

Comment: You want to redo the PDF with new font attributes or do you want to take an already existing PDF and change it?

Comment: No, I don't want to redo. I made an application, which takes inputs from text boxes. eg- Name : abcde fgh. Now I want change the format of the headings like "Name".

Paragraph para= new Paragrah("Name: " + Textbox1.Text);
doc.Add(para);
 I want to change the format of the text "Name".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to change the style and color.

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Helvetica", 16, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED);
Paragraph para= new Paragrah("Name: " + Textbox1.Text, font);
```

There are other options for fonts, see [here](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=11) for examples.

Comment: Do I have to use any name space??